# XSL test for populated field

Tags: xslt

Is there a text I can use to check if a field is populated and toggle the field's display based on the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test for the existence of an element this way:

```
<xsl:if test="/root/parent/node">
  Prints if and only if the expression exists
</xsl:if>
```

If you know the element exists and you're just after whether it has a value or not, use this:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(/root/parent/node) &gt; 0">
  Prints if the expression has a non-empty value
</xsl:if>
```